# Laravel / Sentry login_attribute not changing

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I am trying to implement the ability for a user to login either with their email or a username. At present I have the email login working with the code below, as that is the default set in the `app/config/packages/cartalyst/sentry/config.php` page.

The code I have currently is:

```
$email = Input::get('email');
$password = Input::get('password');
$remember = Input::get('remember_me');

$field = filter_var(Input::get('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';       
Config::set('Cartalyst/Sentry::users.login_attribute', $field);

if(Sentry::authenticate(array($field => $email, 'password' => $password), $remember == 'yes'))
    $destination = Redirect::intended('/');
```

However it keeps throwing the LoginRequiredException provided by Sentry.

However if I change the `login_attribute` in the `config.php` page to username then the login for that works fine but the email side of things stop.

If anyone can shed some light as to why this would be failing? I've added a line to extract the current value of `login_attribute` and that works and changes as anticipated but regardless the exception is still thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The config item is used to set the login attribute at run time, not when actually processing a log in. You can see that being done [in the Sentry service provider](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/blob/master/src/Cartalyst/Sentry/SentryServiceProvider.php#L106-L119). Changing the config item will not affect the actual login attribute name being used, which is [a static property on Sentry's user model](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/blob/master/src/Cartalyst/Sentry/Sentry.php#L169).

You should be able to replace the `Config::set()` command with something like `SentryUser::setLoginAttributeName($field)` (modified for your exact situation) and achieve the results you desire.

Comment: Thanks Cryode, your answer was perfect, in the end I had to use: `Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User` but couldn't of done it without you.